# A span element is always null in javascript function even though exists in aspx code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, getelementbyid

Coding in VS-2012 Express for Web , WebForms, Ajax -- VB.Net.

I want to prevent the user from leaving the page when button-click starts a long server process.  This works perfectly the first time clicking 'cmdDoMonthlyReports' button and letting the process complete to show the results in a [span] element.  But if I click the button a second time, the [span] innerHTML are NOT cleared from the page -- but the process runs again (as expected) with the old results showing in the [span] during the process execution -- which is NOT correct.

The problem is the [span] is NOT cleared when 'SetIsBusy()' js-function is run, because the element oSpan is always null

```
var oSpan = document.getElementById('< %= idSpanResult.ClientID%>');
```

returns as null and thus the innerHTML does not get cleared.

My question is "why" does the oSpan element always null?

Any comments or solutions will be greatly appreciated...thanks.

Here is my markup for the asp.button.

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdDoMonthlyReports" runat="server" Text="Do Monthly Reports"  SkinID="cmdButton" OnClientClick="SetIsBusy(true)"/>
```

Here is the javascript for the ClientClick -- calling 'SetIsBusy(true)'...

```
var m_bIsBusy = false;
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
   var oCtrl = document.getElementById('<%= idIsBusy.ClientID%>');
   //if (oCtrl != null) { m_bIsBusy = (oCtrl.value.toLowerCase() === "true") } else { m_bIsBusy = false; }
   m_bIsBusy = (oCtrl != null) ? (oCtrl.value.toLowerCase() === "true") : false;
   if (m_bIsBusy) {
      return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you leave this page, now, you will lose all of your generated monthly reports.  Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
   } 
}

function SetIsBusy(p_IsBusy) {
   m_bIsBusy = p_IsBusy;
   if (m_bIsBusy == true) {
     var oSpan = document.getElementById('< %= idSpanResult.ClientID%>');
     if (oSpan == null) { oSpan = document.getElementById('idSpanResult'); }
     if (oSpan != null) { oSpan.innerHTML = ''; }
  }
}
```

The button.click also fires on the server in the code-behind where some validations take place and then the long-running process executes. The results of the process are contained in a text-string which updates to the response back to the browser.  Here is that code-behind code.

```
Protected Sub cmdDoMonthlyReports_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDoMonthlyReports.Click
     ...some validation code...
     Call sbGenerateReports()

     Dim sResultText As String = m_sResultsHTML

     idSpanResult.InnerHtml = sResultText
     idSpanResult.Visible = True

     updpnlDetails.Update()

  End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure but I think your space is wrong: `< %=` should be `<%=`

Comment: Could you please show us html snippet of how span tag idSpanResult is declared? Where did you declared SetIsBusy function?

Comment: <asp:Panel ID="pnlProgress" runat="server" visible="true" style="margin: 0.5em; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
       <span id="idSpanResult" runat="server" visible="true">
       </span>
    </asp:Panel>

Comment: @Lucero : Very good eyes!!!, but I have changed the code to remove space , but still does not clear the innerHtml.  Thanks

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu : thanks for reply -- the SetIsBusy() is called when client-click on the button -- see second code block above.  OnClientClick="SetIsBusy(true)"/>

Comment: Okay, have you looked at the browser debuuger and tried to find out what happens there at the time this is executed (e.g. set a breakpoint if possible)?

Comment: JohnD: Is SetIsBusy is written in .aspx page?

Comment: @Lucero : no, but I have breakpoint in the VS aspx-code.  I will try this but am  not familiar with how to debug from the browser.

Comment: Well, since the `document.getElementById()` call is happening on the browser it is the single source of truth. That's where you can see what is really happening, e.g. why it doesn't find the element (wrong ID? missing element? ...)

Comment: @Lucero : IE-11 browser, debug with F12, got this error: The script debugger failed to connect to the target process. 
A debugger is already attached.

Comment: @JohnD You can just place a debugger; statement in first line of SetIsBusy it should attach to already running VS Debugger.

Comment: I guess VS is hooked into the browser... I always directly debug in the browser (which is not IE in my case) so I'm not sure how detailed the breakpoints can be set to break into VS when it is hooked into the browser. However make sure to set the breakpoint only on that statement and not on the full line, e.g. use the text cursor in the editor and hit F9 to set the breakpoint instead of using the mouse.

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu : Yes, I have done that in the VS-aspx code.  Every time the SetIsBusy()-code is break'ed, the oSpan-object is null.  Notice in code-block #3, above I have tried to use the client-id as well as the coded ID...This page is aspx having a Master-Page.

Comment: Are you able to see what is the value of the expression '< %= idSpanResult.ClientID%>' in debugger?

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu : yes ... it is document.getElementById('CPH1_idSpanResult'); // johnd :  which is the is also indicated in the "View Source" from the browser as <span id="CPH1_idSpanResult">
.  .......should the source code for JS use apostrophe ( ' ) or quote ( " ) when defining the elementById??? thx

Comment: @JohnD In SetIsBusy method could you please place alert(document.getElementById('<%=pnlProgress.ClientID').innerHTML) and see if it is returning span tag of spanresult

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu : yes I did this and the returned tag is:       <span id="CPH1_idSpanResult"></span>

Comment: All -- please remember this page uses Ajax in 3 different UpdatePanels.  The button that is clicked is located in the "updpnlFilters" updatepanel and the span."idSpanResult: is located in the  "updpnlDetails" updatepanel .  Do I have to so something to qualify the idSpanResult id-name?

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu : Please remember this page uses Ajax in 3 different UpdatePanels. The button that is clicked is located in the "updpnlFilters" updatepanel and the span."idSpanResult: is located in the "updpnlDetails" updatepanel . Do I have to so something to qualify the idSpanResult id-name?

Comment: @john not sure if that is the case then progess panel object parent for idSpanResult should also be not accesible..could you make the span's clientidmode=static and try accesing the span with id idSpanResult

Comment: Just for testing sake could you try placing span tag outside progress panel?